Saving render result directly to python object without saving on disk
I want to copy render result from memory to python object like list or later on numpy.
(without saving on disk)
After rendering
bpy.ops.render.render()

A new blender image object named "Render Result" appear in images
rendered_image = bpy.data.images.get('Render Result')

When try to access its data
rendered_image.update()

it says :
 Image 'Render Result' does not have any image data

Please let me know what is the correct way of doing so.
thank you.

I feel like this has been asked before, but it’s something I also want to know.

https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/53768
